# set priority on python node

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How I can change the priority of a node written y python?

Im working with the kinect and a haptic device to be used in the chest of a person, after I get the information about the distance of the object and some processing I want to send it through the serial port to the haptic devic, I realized that I have some delays, so I want to change the priority of xecution of the node or some portion of the node ( written in python) in order to get a behavior close to real time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12935/set-priority-on-python-node/) by [Lean2](https://answers.ros.org/users/1756/lean2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-09**:
So you want one node to run before another?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-08**:
Could you explain what you mean by "priority" and what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the `launch-prefix` flag in a `.launch` file, with a value something like "nice -n -1" (`nice` being the UNIX command for setting priority).

However, this feels very much like an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) to me; can you edit the question to explain in more detail what you're trying to do? Using `nice` is a hack; there's probably a better answer.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0